# How do I "fake" slanted text in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, fonts

A font I am using does not have the slanted/oblique variant to it in LaTeX (NB: not italics), and I would like to have slanted text in places.

Is there an easy way to slant text without having to generate entirely new font files and such?

One suggested solution was to do:

```
\renewcommand{\textsl}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[xslant=0.2231153] (X) {#1};}
```

This works well for one or two words, but tikz nodes don't break across lines, so it's not adequate, for, say, a theorem environment.

Obviously, a quick-and-dirty method will not give exceptional kerning or spacing, but I am not concerned about that. However, a 13 degree shear/slant would be desirable.

Comment: what font are you using that doesn't have slants or italics??

Comment: The font, Adobe Minion Pro, has italics, but no oblique characters.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you will have to learn using e.g. Metafont for this.

Comment: not to be an ass, but you should get the font variant of Minion Pro that has what you want, and either use xetex/xelatex, or use metafont and generate the font metric files yourself. 

you are trying to turn every character 13 degrees, which is going to look terrible, and probably be very difficult.

Comment: You can't use metafont to adjust any font that's not authored in metafont.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily in XeLaTeX:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
\fontspec[ItalicFont=*,ItalicFeatures=FakeSlant]{Minion Pro}
```

Highly undesirable, however, if there's any chance you can get a [real italic](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?pid=414411).

Update: why undesirable? Because font outlines are not designed to be distorted! Any sort of transformation besides linear scaling in both directions will change the relationship between the inner/outer curves of the letters, effectively going against the wishes of the font designer.

If you want to highlight something in a different font than the roman and not use italic, try something completely different like a harmonising sans serif, for example.

Comment: Please note the difference between slanted and italic.

Answer (score 6):

Use a font that does have italics. Standard fonts are best unless you're in marketing.

Comment: In LaTeX, you don't want to "fake" or "hack" things. As with pretty much everything, it's better to do it the right way. That's why it's the right way.

Comment: +1 Fonts that have a italics variant work better than slanting a non-italic fonts.

Comment: Please note the difference between slanted and italic.

Answer (score 3):

I use LuaLaTeX, but the following should also work with XeLaTeX. LuaLaTeX, from my experience, is fully backward compatible with good old LaTeX, and it's only marginally slower. And making new, clever macros is a breeze. Anyhow, enough proselytizing.

This is pulled almost directly from one of my documents. Some of it is hackish, yes, but it suits my needs well - and the results are quite respectable.

```
\usepackage{relsize} % For \texttt definition below
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont% Minion Pro, not redistributable?
[Ligatures=TeX,
SlantedFont=*,
SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
BoldSlantedFont=* Bold,
BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}
]{Minion Pro}

\setsansfont% Linux Biolinum O % SIL Open Font License
[Ligatures=TeX,
Extension=.otf,
BoldFont=fxbb,
ItalicFont=fxbri,
BoldItalicFont=fxbri,
BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=1.5}, % Note: This is not currently working in LuaTeX!
SlantedFont=fxbro,
BoldSlantedFont=fxbbo
]{fxbr}

\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans Mono} % "Free License" No General Restictions
\makeatletter
\let\old@texttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{{\smaller\old@texttt{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some macros for shearing, but that will not be what you want either, I guess.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\hshearbox{vertical_prescale_times_shearfactor}{one_divide_by_shearfactor}{content}
% an initial vertical downscale is often necessary for a 3d projection
\newcommand{\hshearbox}[3]{\scalebox{0.866025}[#2]{\rotatebox{210}%
{\scalebox{1.73205}[-0.57735]{\rotatebox{60}{\scalebox{-1.1547}[#1]{#3}}}}}}

%\vshearbox{horizontal_prescale_times_shearfactor}{one_divide_by_shearfactor}{content}
% an initial horizontal downscale is often necessary for a 3d projection
\newcommand{\vshearbox}[3]{\scalebox{#2}[0.866025]{\rotatebox{210}%
{\scalebox{-0.57735}[1.73205]{\rotatebox{60}{\scalebox{#1}[-1.1547]{#3}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XeLaTeX/fontspec answer mentioned above somehow wouldn't work for me, so I came up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand{\slsc}[1]{\fontspec[SmallCapsFeatures={FakeSlant=0.6}]{Linux Libertine O}\textsc{#1}\fontspec[]{Linux Libertine O}}

\begin{document}

    normaltext

    \textsc{textsc}

    \slsc{textslsc} % this will produce slanted small caps

\end{document}
```